# Jmeter : HttpAuthenticator: NEGOTIATE authentication error

Tags: jmeter

I have a UI script where I need AD authentication. If I run that with 10 users its will work perfectly fine. If I give 15 users or more, jmeter throws error in the console and number of threads started coming down.
This is the error in the console "HttpAuthenticator: NEGOTIATE authentication error: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt))" .Is this due to the AD system issue or the application that is currently under test's issue? Someone please help with this.
[Thread dropping image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSze4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) as it looks like you're violoating at least one of them: using GUI mode for testing.

JMeter GUI is supposed to be used for tests development and/or debugging, when it comes to load test execution you should [run your tests in command-line non-GUI mode.](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-non-gui-mode)

If you will be still experiencing the issue take a look at [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), it seems that there are 5 errors in your test. You might want to increase JMeter logging verbosity and [enable JaaS/Kerberos debugging as well](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/security/java-authentication-and-authorization-service-jaas-loginmodule-developers-guide1.html#GUID-E9C5810B-ADB6-4454-869D-B269ECA8145F)

In case everything looks good from JMeter side of things it might be the system under test issue/bottleneck